# Cambiar el nombre de una Base de datos en el Conector de Java

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

estoy realizando un programa para el cual solo usaba una base de datos. Ahora quiero que se conecte a una base de datos especifica según el país del usuario registrado, es decir que verifique de que país es el usuario y cambie automáticamente. La única forma en la que lo he podido hacer es con al variable con el nombre de la db fija. He implementado un JComboBox para validar que se seleccione el pais antes de ingresar y estoy guardando la variable con el país pero al momento de pasarla a la otra clase en otro paquete me dice esto: Unknown database 'null' es decir que no está tomando el valor que le asigno.

Cuando hago esto en otras clases del mismo paquete el valor de las variables si se asigna y lo puedo usar en las demás clases, no sé si tenga que ver o lo estoy haciendo mal, dejo una captura y el codigo.

[image: Captura del código]

En el login estoy declarando la variable como:

public static String bd_pais;

Variable la cual toma el valor del JComboBox al momento de que se seccione el país. La verdad no sé a que se deba y estaría muy agradecido si me pudieran ayudar. Mucha gracias.

Comment: Pon el código como texto, no como captura de pantalla, ya que las imágenes pueden causar problemas y no verse en todos los dispositivos. En segundo lugar, revisa el orden en que se asignan valores a las expresiones.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, aquí dejo el código. Aunque declare el valor que debería tomar la variable "paisg" con la base de datos que quiero acceder no toma el valor, sigue siendo null.

package conexion;

import Vistas.Login;
import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {

```
String Paisg;

public Conexion (){
    Paisg = Login.bd_pais;
    System.out.println(Paisg);
}    

private Connection con = null;
private final String nombreBd = Paisg;
private final String usuario = "root";
private final String password = "";
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + nombreBd + "?useUnicode=true&use"
        + "JDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&"
        + "serverTimezone=UTC";

//Constructor de la clase   
public Connection getConexion() {

    try {
        //Obtener Driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        //Obtener Conexion
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
        if (con != null) {
            //System.out.println("Conexión exitosa a la BD");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ocurre una ClassNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ocurre una SQLException : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return con;

}
```

}